# ProductID cannot be called in Subscription StoreKit2

Tags: ios, swift, storekit2

I cannot call productID in StoreKit2.

I am getting the following error:

> [Default] [StoreKit] Did not receive any products or error for products request.

I am calling with this code.
`productAppID` contains the product ID set in App Store Connect.

```
var storeProducts:[Product].
        storeProducts = try await Product.products(for: [productAppID])]
```

Find out about the cause,
I have my App Store Connect subscription set up and waiting for application.
I have also activated my App Store Connect paid apps.

Subscription test within Xcode works fine.